# change shape of font icon using css

Tags: html, css, fonts, css-shapes

I have downloaded font-icon from flaticon.com

- to change font-icon color we can use css like this:

  ```
  .flaticon-baby23:before {
       content: "\e000";
       color:red;
  }
  ```
- to change size we use this:

  ```
  .flaticon-baby23:before {
       content: "\e000";
       font-size:15px;
  }
  ```

Is ther any method to change shape of font-icon like given in the picture i found those from [here is webiste](http://stackicons.com/)[image]

 Those are various shape

- how do i change icon shape???

my style[image]

Comment: In this case you aren't changing the form of the icon itself just of the container

Comment: @Danko i need to change shape is it possible

Comment: why the shape?  how?  rotate ? scale?

Comment: @Danko my icon are in icon shape how to make them in square background

Comment: check my question that's how am getting my font icon how do i have i con in boxed shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way those icons are changing "shape" is that the border radius, background, and drop-shadow is being applied to them. The icon itself (the twitter bird) is not changing.

Depending on what you are trying to do, you might be able to do the same.

If you are trying to get the edges of the phone font icon to be rounded, that is not possible unless you find one that has that already. If, instead, you are trying to create a background for your icon similar to the twitter icons you showed, style the font icon with a border-radius, background-color and drop-shadow.

Comment: then how do i make that square background

Comment: Don't set a border-radius, just the background-color.

Answer (score 1):

better download other font-icon packs or use background radious method